# Can I imitate fast-forwarded pull if my local branch diverges with remote in Git?

Tags: git, rebase, pull, fast-forward

I have three branches `first`, `second`, and `master`:

```
  D---E---F first
 /
A---B---...---C---... master
               \
                G---H second
```

- `first` is a final version and is waiting to be merged into `master` as a single squashed commit.
- `second` is still under development.

I want to regularly check if `second` merged with `first` will still work properly after new commits appear in `second`.

I have two repositories:

- At `repo1` I simply add new commits `I` and `J` to `second` and push them to `origin`.
- At `repo2` my working branch is `second`, which has been rebased onto `first`. I am never going to push it at all, `repo2` is needed only for local build checks.

```
       repo1
  D---E---F first
 /
A---B---...---C---... master
               \
                G---H---I---J second, origin/second

       repo2
$ git checkout second
$ git rebase first

  D---E---F first
 /
A---B---...---C---... master
 \
  D'--E'--F'--B'--...---C'--G---H second
```

The important thing is that commit `E`(`E'`) causes a long-time rebuild of the whole project, so I want it to never be reapplied again and stay where it is.

That's why I can't use:

```
git pull -r
```

on `second` because it would rearrange all commits and result in this

```
         repo2
A---B---...---C---G---H---I---J---D'--E'--F' second
```

Also, I can't use fast-forwarded pull because `second` in `repo2` and `origin/second` diverge. But my guess is that something like fast-forwarded pull is indeed possible. It should result in the following:

```
         repo2
  D---E---F first
 /
A---B---...---C---... master
 \
  D'--E'--F'--B'--...---C'--G---H---I---J second
```

Can I somehow imitate it with some sequence of Git commands?

Comment: You can rebase instead merging if you want all the commits lines up in single file (and if you don't mind the consequences of rewriting history).

Comment: just a note : what you describe is definitely not a fast forward ... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `repo2` : you can check the state of `origin1/second`, then run `git fetch`, check the new state and try to cherry-pick the delta :

```
before=$(git rev-parse orgin1/second)
git fetch origin1
after=$(git rev-parse orgin1/second)

if [ "$before" != "$after" ]; then
    git checkout second
    git cherry-pick ${before}..${after}
fi
```

---

If you need this to work not just with a hard coded `second` branch but for any active branch you may have :

```
branch=$(git branch --show-current)

before=$(git rev-parse origin1/$branch)
git fetch
...
```

or if you want to pass the branch to fetch as an argument :

```
branch=$1
if [ -z "$branch" ]; then
    branch=$(git branch --show-current)
fi
```

or ...